# php | how to allow only plus sign then numbers like +1 or +44 in php

Tags: php

How can I use regular expressions (regex) to validate phone numbers that include the "+" and "-" signs, as well as numbers?

For example, I want to validate phone numbers in the format of 'country code + phone number', such as '+21260000000' for Morocco or '+447975777666' for the UK.

What regex pattern can I use in PHP to accomplish this validation?

Could you please provide me with a regex pattern in PHP that allows the '+' sign to be part of the phone number output?

because tried so many with perg_match but it comes out with the number without the "+" in the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUX7F.png)

```
<?php

$str = +212600000000 ;

if(preg_match('/^[0-9 +-]+$/', $str)){


echo "Valid phone <br>"; 
echo $str ;
 /*output*/ 
// Valid phone
// 212600000000

}else{ echo "Not valid Phone"; }

?>
```

Comment: Please note, that you can NEVER validate a phone number without some sort of confirmation-message. You can only validate a "looks-like-a-phone-number" String. Hence, ask yourself the question if it does make sence to force a format without actually REALLY beeing able to validate? I would prefer having the number field optional, therefore `null` or empty over 90% of users providing `+0123456789` just to get past "validation".

Comment: Yes totally agree with you, in my case the sign-up form is kind of optional (allows to use a wrong phone number) but it's required to complete the registration and the user will be asked (forced) to confirm his phone number so he can receive the services he asked for, I'm just try to make them fill in the correct format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a pattern which starts with `+`, followed by a country code and other digits:

```
^\+\d+$
```

Your updated PHP script:

```php
$str = "+212600000000";
if (preg_match("/^\+\d+$/", $str)) {
    echo "Valid phone <br>"; 
    echo $str ;
}
else {
    echo "Not valid Phone";
}
```

This prints:

```
Valid phone <br>+212600000000
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and for the "-" is it the same Should I add \-\ in the regex ?

Comment: To allow for dashes, use perhaps: `^\+\d[0-9-]*\d$`

Comment: now I fingered out the issue when input comes from a variable `$str2 = "+212600000000 ;` it works but whenever it comes `$str = $_GET['phone'];` it's not working and also the output comes without the plus sign, really so confused

Comment: just got it, it should be encoded in the URL ` %2b212600000000`  thanks man for help